# Can not add bootstrap class with button using Django and Python

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add bootstrap class in button using Django and Python but it could not added at all. I am providing my code below:

control.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<center><h1>Welcome</h1>
<div class="boxwidthdiv">
<form method="post" action="{% url 'plantsave' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="boxwidthinnerdiv">
        Nuclear Mini Plant <br /><br />
        <select name="react">
            <option value="Reactor1">Reactor 1</option>
            <option value="Reactor2">Reactor 2</option>
            <option value="Reactor3">Reactor 3</option>
        </select>
        <br /><br /><br /><br />
        <button class="buttondiv" name="strt" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Start</button>
        <button class="buttondiv" name="shutbt" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Shut Down</button>
        <button class="buttondiv" name="susbtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Suspend</button>
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>Nuclear Reactor</h1>
      {% if count > 0  %}
      <b>Hi, {{ user.username }}</b>
        <a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a>
        <a href="{% url 'view_reactor' %}">View Reactor status</a>
        <a href="{% url 'logout' %}">logout</a>
      {% else %}
        <a href="{% url 'login' %}">login</a> / <a href="{% url 'signup' %}">signup</a>
      {% endif %}
      <hr>
    </header>
    <main>
      {% block content %}
      {% endblock %}
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here I could not added the classes at all.

Comment: You have double `class` attributes on your elements. Put all classes into one attribute.

Comment: Thanks yes,it was my silly mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having the same attribute twice on an element (e.g. `class`) is invalid HTML. Instead of

```
<button class="buttondiv" name="strt" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Start</button>
<button class="buttondiv" name="shutbt" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Shut Down</button>
<button class="buttondiv" name="susbtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Suspend</button>
```

go for

```
<button class="buttondiv btn btn-success" name="strt" type="submit">Start</button>
<button class="buttondiv btn brn-danger" name="shutbt" type="submit">Shut Down</button>
<button class="buttondiv btn btn-info" name="susbtn" type="submit">Suspend</button>
```

---

**On a sidenote:**

You might want to rename your CSS classes. `buttondiv` is very HTML-centric and leaks its scope (button in a div). A better approach is usually to either use element-type selectors (e.g. `div button`) or use more domain related terms for CSS classes (e.g. `call-to-action` or `entry-operation`). This will help you later on whenever you want to apply the same style elsewhere or introduce other classes with similar scope.

Same goes for the element names here, which seem to be lacking consistency.